# Max Volume out of a square with a open rectangular box(can you confirm my proof?)

Tags: calculus, analysis, education

I have a simply proof to do, but just want to get your thoughts on it if i haven't forgot something:

I have a squared piece of metal with the side length of $ a $ and i need to cut out a open rectangular box out of it by cutting out the same quadratic edges.

My drawing of the problem (at least how i understand it):

[image]

x is in my calculation the length of one side at one of the blue squares

The definition of the volume for a rectangular box is: $$ V = a * b *c $$

since the shape we cut out the rectangular box is a square, $ a = b $ and there for:

$$ V = (a-2x) * (a-2x) * x$$

By multiplication i get:

$$ V = (a^2 - 4ax + 4x^2) * x$$
$$ V = (a^2x - 4ax^2 + 4x^3)$$

The first derivative of V is:

$$ V' = 12x^2-8ax+a^2 $$
and i need to find the zero points:

$$ V' = 12x^2-8ax+a^2 = 0 $$

therefor, using the quadratic formula i get:

$$ \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{(b^2)+4ac}}{2*a}$$

and $ a = 12 $, $ b = -8a $ and $ c = a^2 $

$$ \frac{-(-8a) \pm \sqrt{(-8a)^2+4 * 12 * a^2}}{2 * 12} $$
$$ \frac{8a \pm \sqrt{64a^2+48a^2}}{24} $$
$$ \frac{8a \pm \sqrt{16a^2}}{24} $$
$$ \frac{8a \pm 4a}{24} $$

and therefor $$ x_1 = \frac{a}{2} $$

and $$ x_2 = \frac{a}{6} $$

End of proof.

Is my proof correct or am i on the wrong path?

Thanks in advance everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Overall, you are doing right steps. However, since you cut the squares from both sides of the metal sheet, the width of the box is $a-2x$. In addition, it's easier to first define the width/length of the box $y$ and then calculate the height as $(a-y)/2$. The math will be simpler.

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo with (a-x) instead of (a-2x). If it's okay for you, i would like to see an example with your (a-y)/2 approach. I think i know what you mean but im not 100% sure